# Launch fb-messenger from intent using app_scope_id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am trying to send open fb-messenger in a specific chat with a user from within my app. I have the user's app_scope_id, relevant for my app. However, from what I could figure out so far, I need the global facebook id in order for the messenger to launch in a conversation with that person. Is there any way to achieve that with the app_scope_id?

**Code:**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/");
uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,[APP SCOPE ID]);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: There is not. There is no supported way to open messenger.

Comment: It just seems so bizarre. Why would facebook make it so difficult for me to use another one of their apps? They're literally **ckblocking themselves...

Comment: This does however work for iOS. I tried it.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for that?

Comment: @WizKid Are you sure for now?